# JDBC MySQL Editing/Updating a current Entry in the Database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

How can I edit a certain data entry in MySQL? for example I have table about a personal information, but I only want to edit the First Name table, can i just do it like this?

```
"Update Personal_Info
set first_name='"+getFirstName()+"' ,last_name = ?
where emp_id = 2011-01015"
```

Where the question mark in the last name will retain it's value.I am using this kind of approach, because I  do not want to hard code everything. you see in my UI , I'll use a form where the user will  choose if he want's to update only the first name and last name. I came up with this idea since it would be easier for me. but suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include only those columns whose value you want to update. Suppose if you want to update first_name then statement will be:

```
String sql="Update Personal_Info set first_name=? where emp_id=?";
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1,getFirstName()); // set parameter value for first_name
ps.setString(2,"2011-01015");   //     parameter value for emp_id    
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
conn.close();
```

EDIT:

```
String sql="Update Personal_Info set first_name=? where emp_id='2011-01015'";
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1,getFirstName()); // set parameter value for first_name
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
conn.close();
```

Comment: @user962206 - You can use variable or something like getEmpid().

Comment: other than that? can I just setString(1,defaultvalueofthatfield); is there anything like that or retain it's current value??

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry for giving a late feedback, this was still last years but it did help! sorry. anyways thank you soo much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this way.
But you should consider using [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to omit possible SQL injections in your app.

Comment: wiht the question mark, I mean I will retain the current value of last name

Comment: then how could I do that?? is there any way?